# How to create composite-primary-key in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, composite-primary-key

Please help me to convert this PostgreSQL table to rails migration file and model

```
CREATE DATABASE ip2location WITH ENCODING 'UTF8'; \c ip2location

CREATE TABLE ip2location_db1(
  ip_from integer(10) NOT NULL,
  ip_to integer(10) NOT NULL,
  country_code character(2) NOT NULL,
  country_name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ip2location_db1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ip_from, ip_to)
);
```

- Do i want to create rails model to retrieve data

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a solution that works

```
 def change
  create_table :ip2_location_v4s, id: false do |t|
   t.integer :ip_from
   t.integer :ip_to
   t.string :country_code
   t.string :country_name
  end

  execute "ALTER TABLE ip2_location_v4s ADD PRIMARY KEY (ip_from, ip_to);"
end
```

This generated the SQL table that I needed

-- Table: ip2_location_v4s

-- DROP TABLE ip2_location_v4s;

```
CREATE TABLE ip2_location_v4s
(
 ip_from bigint NOT NULL,
 ip_to bigint NOT NULL,
 country_code character varying(2) NOT NULL,
 country_name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT ip2_location_v4s_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ip_from, ip_to)
)
```

Thanks @mohammad-shahadat-hossain for your time

Comment: How do we represent this as model ?

Answer (score 2):

For migration script

```
class Iplocation2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :ip2location_db1, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :ip_from 
    t.integer :ip_to
    t.string :country_code
    t.string :country_name
    t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

For model

```
class ip2location < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :ip_from,:ip_to
  validates :language_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:id] }
end
```

Comment: I have just created migration file

'code'  class CreateIp2LocationV4s < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ip2_location_v4s, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :ip_from, :limit => 8, :null => false
      t.integer :ip_to, :limit => 8, :null => false
      t.string :country_code, :limit => 2 ,:null => false
      t.string :country_name, :limit => 64, :null => false

      add_index :ip2_location_v4s, ["ip_from", "ip_to"], :unique => true
    end
  end
end '

Comment: did you run `rake db:migrate` after creating the migration file ?

Comment: Yes but i got error,

rake aborted!
<code> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "ip2_location_v4s" does not exist <code>

Comment: First `rake db:reset` if it doesn't work then run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

Comment: Thanks, I will check your solution, Still no luck , may be my side error, lets see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105866/discussion-between-nil-salu-and-mohammad-shahadat-hossain).

Comment: Hi without "add_index :ip2_location_v4s, ["ip_from", "ip_to"], :unique => true", it successfully migrated  to DB